# android version 4.4 devices doesn't work with google's mobile vision , isOperational returns false

Tags: android, vision

i made an app that uses Mobile Vision library to Read Text .

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

but turns out my app doesn't work with all android 4.4 versions

the " isOperational " always returns False .

here's the logcat :

```
    E/TextNativeHandle: Error creating remote native handle
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fb.zzDR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fb.isOperational(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer.isOperational(Unknown Source)
at MY_PACKAGE_NAME.ReadingActivity.onCreate(ReadingActivity.java:101)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 16:24:24.185 2365-2365/MY_PACKAGE_NAME E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
```

UPDATE :

here's the ReadingActivity class:

```
public class ReadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   


    private SurfaceView camView;

    private CameraSource camSource;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading);


     camView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.scnView);

TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

if (!txtRecognizer.isOperational()) {

            // showing an error message 
            Toast.makeText(this ,"FALSE" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {


            camSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), txtRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280,1024)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .build();

            //  starting cam view
            camView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                    try {

                        // check if permissions is granted
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            return;
                        }
                        // starting the camera
                        camSource.start(camView.getHolder());
                        // starting the focus on touch method
                        initCameraFocusListener();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

                    camSource.stop();
                }
            });


            txtRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {

                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                   final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();

                    if (items.size() != 0) {


                       /// dealing with the results here 



                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

i tested 4 android 4.3 and 4.4 devices and same problem . 
they all have a good free storage space . 
any idea to solve this ?

Comment: Try to use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'`

Comment: this version not working on my android studio i don't know why? i updated my android studio but still ..

Comment: ok i just tried your suggestion but the problem still on.

Comment: add the code of `ReadingActivity` and/or another related classes to your question

Comment: ok i just updated my question  : )

Comment: could you please test this code on version 4.4 just to see what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Google Play Services on your devices.

Possibly the same problem as here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/97

Comment: is google play services installed in all devices by default ? or should i ask my users to download it manualy ?

Comment: Normally it's installed on most devices and auto-updated. But at the same time you can always find some cheap Chinese phones without it... Note also that it is not installed on simulators (btw, you can install manually with http://opengapps.org)

Comment: thank you so much Anton! i will put this error message in my app hopefully users will fix the problem when they update it.